# Create database table in Django via python (Field type)

Tags: python, sql, django

The problem specifically is that I can create the type of data found in the Django database using python, is that the model I have Django, there BigIntegerField, IntegerField and DecimalField but I can not make the same kind of data using python, the idea is to make my python code automatically update the database, here the code:

Django Model

```
unidad = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=15)
pin = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
fecha = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=1)
```

Python execute

```
cursor.execute('''create table u_%(table_name)s stocks (id integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,id_unidad bigint NOT NULL, pin integer NOT NULL, fecha numeric(7, 1) NOT NULL)''' % dict(table_name = table_name))
```

This is the output of Django when I run "python manage.py sql gprs"

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `evento` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `unidad` bigint NOT NULL,
    `pin` integer NOT NULL,
    `fecha` numeric(7, 1) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to automatically update the database *schema*? That is, if you add a field to your model, to have the python code automatically add the fields in your database? Django isn't really built to do this (the built-in command line option [syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) will only create *new* tables, not modify existing ones) but you can take a look at something like [south](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Comment: This is already solved, which wanted to do was a Django database and feed it in python code automatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of confusing.  To see the actual sql that django uses to create your model prior to executing `python manage.py syncdb`, you can use `python manage.py sql appname` as documented here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sql-appname-appname

Comment: I have the same problem even with the help you gave me to know how Django was creating the table:  line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value), line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'stocks (id integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,id_unidad bigint NOT NULL' at line 1")

Comment: @user987055 your sql doesn't look valid `u_%(table_name)s stocks` do you want to create a table called stocks or insert your table name?